# Inheritance within object literals

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, javascript-objects, prototype-chain

```
 function Car(model, color, power){
    this.model = model;
    this.color = color;
    this.power = power;
    this.is_working = true;
    this.sound = function(){
        console.log("Vrummm!");
    };
}
 function Car_optionals(){
     this.turbo_boost = true;
     this.extra_horsepower = 20;
     this.name_tag = "Badass";
 }

Car.prototype = new Car_optionals();
var Audi = {};
Audi.prototype = new Car();
console.log(Audi.is_working);
```

So i'm having this too classes Car and Car_optionals and I want the newly crated object Audi to inherit proprietyes from both Car and Car_optionals classes. It is posible to inherit proprietyes and methods within object literals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is posible to inherit proprietyes and methods within object literals?

Not yet, but with ES6, this will be possible:

```
var foo = {
    __proto__: bar
};
```

where `bar` becomes the prototype of `foo`.

However, I rather think you mean whether it's possible to create objects with a specific prototype. You can use [**`Object.create`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) for that:

```
var foo = Object.create(bar);
```

Or if you have an already existing object, you can use [**`Object.setPrototypeOf`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf):

```
foo.setPrototypeOf(bar);
```

In your specific case though, there is no value in setting the prototype of `Audi` to anything, because `Car` and `Car_optionals` don't define anything on their `prototype` objects. Everything is set inside the functions itself, so you simply have to apply those functions to `Audi`:

```
Car.call(Audi, 'A4', 'blue', 180);
Car_optionals.call(Audi);
```

And the more natural way would be to create a new instance through `Car`:

```
var Audi = new Car('A4', 'blue', 180);
Car_optionals.call(Audi);
```

Comment: well the call() function will do the trick for me. that was what I was looking for. thx!